# Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID

Tags: powershell

I'm getting the following error when I run a script. It takes a few loops before it starts popping up.

```
New-Object : Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID 
{0002DF01-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} from the IClassFactory failed due to the 
following error: 80004005 Unspecified error (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004005 
(E_FAIL)).
At C:\Users\Script.ps1:210 
char:13
+       $ie = New-Object -Com "InternetExplorer.Application"
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [New-Object], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoCOMClassIdentified,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are constantly creating a new Internet Explorer Com object in a loop without destroying it when you are finished with it, you are bound to get the `ResourceUnavailable` error at some point.

Put this in your code (loop) when you are done using the object to clear it from memory:

```
$ie.Quit()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($ie) | Out-Null
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```