# New-Object -ComObject excel.application

Tags: excel, comobject

I suspect there may have been some change recently, either to my own work computer or my company's 365 subscription, that has alter the behavior of a frequently used script. Specifically, with this line:

*emphasized text*New-Object -ComObject excel.application

Consistently, every time the script is run *in full* I receive this error:

*New-Object : Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} from the IClassFactory failed due
to the following error: 80010108 The object invoked has disconnected from its clients. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010108
(RPC_E_DISCONNECTED)).*

However, if I *manually* progress through he script regions at a time, although he line might fail initially, it will typically succeed the next.

I have tried debug to slow the process down, as well as adding a sleep time, with no joy.

Any ideas as to what may have changed? This script has run without issue for months until recently. My suspicion is that it's a timing/licensing issue. I will be getting a local Office installation as I have read of some successes in doing so, but this will not be  viable solution, if it works, long term.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the available ressource handles are exhausted. Check this
[Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53640628/creating-an-instance-of-the-com-component-with-clsid)

Comment: Thanks! This make sense. I will test.   I was just informed that there was indeed a change in our 365 licensing, from E3 to E5, the very week this issue presented. Coincidence perhaps?